# How do I request publish streams like this with my app?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk

I have two questions.

1 - how can my app request publish stream like this, all in one screen?

[image]

2 - is it possible to make a app like two or more pages, I already can make people like using signed_request, but lets assume I'll get people's permission, is there any way to make people like a different page?

Example: after people "like" my page where the app is, I'll get permission, then my app use this permission to like a different page or url, any way?

Comment: In your second question, are you asking how you can "like" pages on behalf of users who have granted you certain permissions? I'm not an FB user, but that sounds abusive to me - surely that enables you to create endorsements that your users might not be willing to give themselves?

Comment: Yes i think that too just trying to figure out how people do that

Comment: May I ask why, if you plan not to use it? Readers here may be curious, so I might as well ask first!

Answer (score 1):

Answering the first part:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if (!$user) {
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
           'scope'=>'publish_stream,status_update',
           'redirect_uri'=>'http://yourlink/'));
echo "<p>Redirecting to permission request...</p>";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
} else {
... your app.
}
```

You put the permissions in the scope element. The approval box you get will depend on whichever elements you put there. Only ask for permissions you actually need though.

--- EDIT ---

In response to your comments, you also need the following if you are uploading pics using the SDK:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
```

You do that once you have authenticated.

You also need a few more permissions:

```
'scope'=> 'read_stream, publish_stream, photo_upload, user_photos, user_photo_video_tags'
```

You may not need all of those, depending on what you are trying to do, so once you get it working try removing the video portion for example.

I spent a while on this last year, you may find these posts useful:

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=262

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=322

Comment: I need to creat an album, upload a photo mabe publish_actions?

Comment: What do you mean by it appears in another page? Can you add a screenshot to your example above?

If you are trying to upload pictures you also need a few other perms, I will add them to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Publish stream is an extended permission so it appears in another auth dialog window, the screenshot you are showing is probably old. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/